# FreeBSD on Raspberry Pi 1 B+ - system SD Card read/write is super slow

Tags: freebsd, raspberry-pi, disk, sd-card

I have installed an official FreeBSD 13-RELEASE on Raspberry Pi 1 B+ (armv6l) with a Goodram Class 10 16GB SD Card, yet the disk read/write speed is super slow (186 kbytes/sec):

```
# diskinfo -tv /dev/mmcsd0
/dev/mmcsd0
        512             # sectorsize
        15634268160     # mediasize in bytes (15G)
        30535680        # mediasize in sectors
        4194304         # stripesize
        0               # stripeoffset
        SDHC SD16G 2.0 SN 00000247 MFG 04/2021 by 254 42        # Disk descr.
        00000247        # Disk ident.
                        # Attachment
        Yes             # TRIM/UNMAP support
        0               # Rotation rate in RPM

Seek times:
        Full stroke:      250 iter in   0.954876 sec =    3.820 msec
        Half stroke:      250 iter in   0.946644 sec =    3.787 msec
        Quarter stroke:   500 iter in   1.888141 sec =    3.776 msec
        Short forward:    400 iter in   1.510555 sec =    3.776 msec
        Short backward:   400 iter in   1.510279 sec =    3.776 msec
        Seq outer:       2048 iter in   7.485804 sec =    3.655 msec
        Seq inner:       2048 iter in   7.220448 sec =    3.526 msec

Transfer rates:
        outside:       102400 kbytes in 549.596899 sec =      186 kbytes/sec
        middle:        102400 kbytes in 549.520508 sec =      186 kbytes/sec
        inside:        102400 kbytes in 547.767644 sec =      187 kbytes/sec
```

Uname:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD rpi-b 13.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 13.0-RELEASE #0 releng/13.0-n244733-ea31abc261f: Fri Apr  9 06:30:27 UTC 2021     root@releng1.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/arm.armv6/sys/RPI-B  arm
```

The overall system speed is super slow either (e.g. boot time is ~ 5 min). Any thoughts what is to be done here?

Comment: Just judging on the knowledge of the other models: Some RB-Pi need max 2GB sd card, what is hard to buy now. It is recomended to save all the OS on USB (flash or HD) except of /boot and MBR, of course. With some models it is possible to set up the RB-Pi to boot form USB only, without need of any SD card. I have not seen the RB-Pi running FreeBSD, lot of users run raspberian clon of debian. Cannot confirm the idea to create just 2GB volume on the SD card.

Comment: @schweik, I had been running Arch Linux ARM on this very SBC for years prior, both with SD for /boot and 8GB USB flash for /, as well as 16GB and 32GB SDs for everything, and there had been zero problems with these. I wonder if it is something wrong with the FreeBSD armv6l implementation, or simply the card is faulty.

Comment: well I tried to remember all my problems with RB-Pi but I never used FreBSD runnig on it. I can recommend to move in bootloader the root directory to another blockdevice - other USB disk, to see if it helps. Also it could be a good practise to enable deep level of logging and analyse the log output. On the other hand the SD cards are flash based, so too many writes can dramaticaly slow down the response.

Comment: The solution must be some combiantion of this: Try to move the root dir to another blockdevice, reduce the amount of needless writes ro the SD card (do not modify access time ...), analyse the bootlogs and try to find the bottleneck. I hope there must be some FreeBSD - ARM forum where you can get more qualified answers. With a very thiny OS you can load the OS into the RAMdisk, and you can see the speed.

Comment: Please check (1) whether the driver is configured using the card in 4-bit-mode or slow SPI mode and (2) the speed of the SDIO clock.

Comment: @Philippos please elaborate, this indeed might be the issue. I have not succeeded in finding any proper info.

Comment: @Philippos here is the dmesg output: `dmesg | grep -i mmc | less
mmc0: <MMC/SD bus> on sdhci_bcm0
mmc0: Card at relative address 1 failed to set high speed timing
mmcsd0: 16GB <SDHC SD16G 2.0 SN 00000247 MFG 04/2021 by 254 42> at mmc0 0.4MHz/4bit/65535-block`

Comment: 400 kbit/s in 4 bit mode would be 200 kbyte/s, with a little overhead it's the results you saw. Do you see any more details on why high speed timing failed (if you don't grep for `mmc`? You could narrow the problem by trying with a different card vendor (maybe Goodram breaks some spec).

Comment: FWIW. RPi3 (ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4)  works fine in 12.2 ``mmcsd0: 16GB <SDHC SU16G 8.0 SN 1CCBFA6F MFG 10/2012 by 3 SD> at mmc0 50.0MHz/4bit/65535-block``. Testing low volume Nagios without problems ``12:00AM  up 89 days, 23:38, 1 user, load averages: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00``.

Comment: FWIW. RPi Zero (ARM ARM1176 r0p7) works fine in 13.0 ``mmcsd0: 16GB <SDHC SU16G 8.0 SN 00736959 MFG 06/2013 by 3 SD> at mmc0 50.0MHz/4bit/65535-block``. Without any load for occasional testing only ``9:34PM  up 33 days, 18:34, 1 user, load averages: 0.01, 0.02, 0.00``.

Answer (score 0):

Sandisk Ultra SDHC 16G works for me

---

- RPi Zero (ARM ARM1176 r0p7) in 13.0
- mmcsd0: 16GB <SDHC SU16G 8.0 SN 00736959 MFG 06/2013 by 3 SD> at mmc0 50.0MHz/4bit/65535-block
- Without any load for occasional testing only
- 9:34PM  up 33 days, 18:34, 1 user, load averages: 0.01, 0.02, 0.00

```
root@rpi-b:~ # diskinfo -tv /dev/mmcsd0
/dev/mmcsd0
    512             # sectorsize
    15931539456     # mediasize in bytes (15G)
    31116288        # mediasize in sectors
    4194304         # stripesize
    0               # stripeoffset
    SDHC SU16G 8.0 SN 00736959 MFG 06/2013 by 3 SD  # Disk descr.
    00736959        # Disk ident.
                    # Attachment
    Yes             # TRIM/UNMAP support
    0               # Rotation rate in RPM

Seek times:
    Full stroke:      250 iter in   0.176581 sec =    0.706 msec
    Half stroke:      250 iter in   0.346380 sec =    1.386 msec
    Quarter stroke:   500 iter in   0.318554 sec =    0.637 msec
    Short forward:    400 iter in   0.249260 sec =    0.623 msec
    Short backward:   400 iter in   0.242115 sec =    0.605 msec
    Seq outer:   2048 iter in   1.541124 sec =    0.753 msec
    Seq inner:   2048 iter in   1.592520 sec =    0.778 msec

Transfer rates:
    outside:       102400 kbytes in   6.119237 sec =    16734 kbytes/sec
    middle:        102400 kbytes in   6.354481 sec =    16115 kbytes/sec
    inside:        102400 kbytes in   6.650328 sec =    15398 kbytes/sec
```

---

- RPi3 (ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4) in 12.2
- mmcsd0: 16GB <SDHC SU16G 8.0 SN 1CCBFA6F MFG 10/2012 by 3 SD> at mmc0 50.0MHz/4bit/65535-block.
- Testing low volume Nagios without problems
- 12:00AM  up 89 days, 23:38, 1 user, load averages: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

```
root@rpi-3:~ # diskinfo -tv /dev/mmcsd0
/dev/mmcsd0
    512             # sectorsize
    15931539456     # mediasize in bytes (15G)
    31116288        # mediasize in sectors
    4194304         # stripesize
    0               # stripeoffset
    SDHC SU16G 8.0 SN 1CCBFA6F MFG 10/2012 by 3 SD  # Disk descr.
    1CCBFA6F        # Disk ident.
    Yes             # TRIM/UNMAP support
    0               # Rotation rate in RPM

Seek times:
    Full stroke:      250 iter in   0.825192 sec =    3.301 msec
    Half stroke:      250 iter in   0.533887 sec =    2.136 msec
    Quarter stroke:   500 iter in   0.648232 sec =    1.296 msec
    Short forward:    400 iter in   0.198193 sec =    0.495 msec
    Short backward:   400 iter in   1.061558 sec =    2.654 msec
    Seq outer:   2048 iter in   1.054052 sec =    0.515 msec
    Seq inner:   2048 iter in   0.821306 sec =    0.401 msec

Transfer rates:
    outside:       102400 kbytes in   5.042619 sec =    20307 kbytes/sec
    middle:        102400 kbytes in   4.768441 sec =    21475 kbytes/sec
    inside:        102400 kbytes in   5.317633 sec =    19257 kbytes/sec
```

Comment: In which respect does this answer the question ("what is to be done here")?

Comment: In providing working examples, obviously.  (With respect to your comment "You could narrow the problem by trying with a different card vendor").